Lie group structure on homogeneous spaces
I'm studying Luiz A. B. San Martin's Lie Groups. I am trying to solve the following exercise, but I don't know how to approach it. The exercise says:
$\S$7.5, Exercise 11. Let $G$ be the group of matrices $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & x & z \\
  0 & 1 & y \\
  0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\right)$$
with $x$, $y$, $z$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\Gamma \subseteq G$ the subgroup of matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that the manifold $G/\Gamma$ does not admit a group structure that makes it a Lie group.
Any help will be really appreciated.

What are your thoughts? What do you know about topological properties of Lie groups? Did you study algebraic topology?

Dear @MoisheKohan, Thank you for your message. Unfortunately, this has been one of those exercises where I can not come up with a any idea. I have not studied algebraic topology yet; I have only read the appendix provided in the book about covering spaces (chapter 7).
I would be very grateful if someone could give me any hint or indicate what I should study to tackle this exercise.

Hmm... Does your book discuss the Eckmann-Hilton argument by any chance? Without knowing about fundamental groups you will have hard time solving this problem and knowing covering spaces is useful but is not enough.

❤️ Thank you so much @MoisheKohan!!! I understand, so I will try again when I learn to calculate fundamental groups (the following exercise is about $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) / SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and I have the same problem ). By the way, just out of curiosity, what is the fundamental group of $G / \Gamma$?

It is $\Gamma$ assuming that $G$ is simply connected. You will learn this by reading any algebraic topology book.
